# Android app to fetch data from an on-premise server

Tags: android, caching, on-premises-instances

A company stores its data on an on-premise server. We need to build an android app that will need to fetch files on that server and be available for users to view and download. They mentioned that they do not have an api that we can use to connect and communicate, and something about cache dipping be used.

can someone help understand how are they storing data and how to retrieve that in a custom built android app

Comment: What is an on premise server?

Comment: Hoe they store data looks irrelevant to me.

Comment: You should tell us how data has to be retrieved. After that we can help you with building your Android app.

Comment: No API? Well which protocol has to be used?

Comment: @blackapps On-premise server is a physical server machine, and not one hosted on a popular cloud service like AWS , Azure etc. It is a big hospital and they store data on there server connected to their HIS system. We know how to build data. Don't know to retrieve in such an architecture, which is what the question is about

Comment: You have not given the info asked for. You answer does not help.